# Laravel npm run watch browser sync don't run localhost:3000

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, browser-sync

I have a laravel webpack Browsersync and thats worked on win7. I reinstall my windows and upgraded to win10 and now after i run `npm run watch` the server http://localhost:3000 keeps 'waiting for server'. So the webpack Browsersync is working but i have no server to check my application. What should be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you try this:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

Comment: Don't dump the answer with just "try this", you need more explainations about the changes and how the code works.